# What is the "minimal" way to turn a Hermitian matrix with zeros on the diagonal into a positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose one has an Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix, $H$, where every diagonal element is equal to zero. We can add a diagonal matrix $D$ to $H$ such that the sum is positive semidefinite, $H + D \ge0$. Let $\cal S$ be the set of all such $D$ that satisfy this condition, and define $D_{min}$ as a $D\in{\cal S}$ such that $tr(D_{min})\le tr(D)$ for all $D\in{\cal S}$.

How do we find a suitable $D_{min}$?

A generalization, which would also be useful for me, is as follows: Given a set of probabilities, $p_j\ge0$, $\sum_jp_j=1$, define $P$ to be the diagonal matrix with the $p_j$ appearing along the diagonal in the given order. Then, instead of defining $D_{min}$ as above (which is the special case when all $p_j$ are equal to each other), we define it such that $tr(PD_{min})\le tr(PD)$ for all $D\in{\cal S}$.

Again, how do we find a suitable $D_{min}$?

For a $2\times2$ matrix with off-diagonal element $x$ (and $x^\ast$, its complex conjugate), the answer is fairly straighforward. Let the diagonal elements of $D$ be $d_1,d_2$. Then $det(H+D)\ge0$ implies $d_1d_2\ge|x|^2$, and minimizing $p_1d_1+p_2|x|^2/d_1\le p_1d_1+p_2d_2=tr(PD)$ yields $d_1=\sqrt{\frac{p_2}{p_1}}|x|$ and $d_2=\sqrt{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}|x|$. But even for $n=3$, it already appears to be much more difficult.